# Count number of left nodes in BST

Tags: binary-tree

Given a BST, I am required to find the number of left nodes of the tree.

Example: `

```
          +---+
          | 3 |
          +---+
         /     \
     +---+     +---+
     | 5 |     | 2 |
     +---+     +---+
    /         /     \
+---+     +---+     +---+
| 1 |     | 4 |     | 6 |
+---+     +---+     +---+
         /
     +---+
     | 7 |
     +---+`
```

The answer should be 4, as (5, 1 , 4, 7) are all left nodes of the tree.

What I am thinking of doing is:

```
public int countLeftNodes() {
    return countLeftNodes(overallRoot, 0);
}

private int countLeftNodes(IntTreeNode overallRoot, int count) {
    if (overallRoot != null) {
        count += countLeftNodes(overallRoot.left, count++);    
        count = countLeftNodes(overallRoot.right, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

I know it is wrong, but I don't know why. Could someone explain why, and also help me with the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The second recursion branch overwrites the value from the first. Also you should add 1 for the left root.

Something like:

```
private int countLeftNodes(IntTreeNode node) {
    int count = 0;
    if (node.left != null) 
        count += 1 + countLeftNodes(node.left);    

    if (node.right != null)
        count += countLeftNodes(node.right);


    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to propagate an accumulator (the `count` parameter) down the call stack, since you aren't relying on tail-recursion.

```
public int countLeftNodes(IntTreeNode node) {
    // This test is only needed if the root node can be null.
    if (node == null) return 0;

    int count = 0;
    if (node.left != null) {
        count += 1 + countLeftNodes(node.left);
    }
    if (node.right != null) {
        count += countLeftNodes(node.right);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second line here

```
count += countLeftNodes(overallRoot.left, count++);    
count = countLeftNodes(overallRoot.right, count);
```

you discard the previous value of count. Perhaps it should be `+=` instead of `=`.

I would however express it like this:

```
private int countLeftNodes(IntTreeNode root) {
    return (root.left  == null ? 0 : countLeftNodes(root.left) + 1) +
           (root.right == null ? 0 : countLeftNodes(root.right));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to restructure your code a little. Instead of passing current count for left nodes, just receive it from the two children and add them up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant solution is this one. Yes, of course I'm biased. I'm human :-)

```
def countLeft (node,ind):
    if node == null: return 0
    return ind + countLeft (node->left, 1) + countLeft (node->right, 0)

total = countLeft (root, 0)
```

By passing down the indicator for left nodes, it simplifies what has to be passed up. The following diagram shows each sum being passed up - you start at the bottom and each null passes up 0.

Each node on the left passes up 1 plus whatever came from both branches below. Each node on the right passes up 0 plus whatever came from both branches below.

The root adds nothing since it is neither a left nor right node (it's treated the same as right).

```
                        4
                        ^
                        |
                      +---+
                      | 3 |
            __________+---+__________
           /2                       2\
      +---+                           +---+
      | 5 |                           | 2 |
      +---+                           +---+
     /1                              /2   0\
 +---+                          +---+       +---+
 | 1 |                          | 4 |       | 6 |
 +---+                          +---+       +---+
/0   0\                        /1   0\     /0   0\
                          +---+
                          | 7 |
                          +---+
                         /0   0\
```

---

You can see the operation from this complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sNode { int val; struct sNode *left, *right; } tNode;

#define setNode(N,V,L,R) N.val = V; N.left = L; N.right = R

int countLeft (tNode *node, int ind) {
    if (node == NULL) return 0;
    int x = ind + countLeft (node->left, 1) + countLeft (node->right, 0);
    printf ("Node %d passing up %d\n", node->val, x);
    return x;
}

int main (void) {
    tNode n3, n5, n1, n2, n4, n6, n7;
    setNode (n3, 3, &n5, &n2);
    setNode (n5, 5, &n1, NULL);
    setNode (n1, 1, NULL, NULL);
    setNode (n2, 2, &n4, &n6);
    setNode (n4, 4, &n7, NULL);
    setNode (n7, 7, NULL, NULL);
    setNode (n6, 6, NULL, NULL);

    printf ("countLeft is %d\n", countLeft (&n3, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs the debugging lines:

```
Node 1 passing up 1
Node 5 passing up 2
Node 7 passing up 1
Node 4 passing up 2
Node 6 passing up 0
Node 2 passing up 2
Node 3 passing up 4
countLeft is 4
```

The non-debugging version of the `countLeft` function is as simple as the pseudo-code at the start of this answer:

```
int countLeft (tNode *node, int ind) {
    if (node == NULL) return 0;
    return ind + countLeft (node->left, 1) + countLeft (node->right, 0);
}
```

Comment: @Catie: no, because the first thing it does is check for null, then return 0 in that case. This is a standard way to do it so you don't have to treat the root node as special.

Answer (score 0):

Function to count left nodes (having left child only:
what you can do use a recursive approach, which returns 1 if there only left child is present.

```
    int count_left_nodes(tree_type* root)
     {

     if(root == NULL)       
        return 0;
     if(root->left != NULL && root->right==NULL)      
        return 1;            
     else 
        return count_left_nodes(root->left)+
            count_left_nodes(root->right); 

     }
```