# Maximum number of left nodes/children in a path

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find a way to output the amount of most left nodes **found in a path.**
For example:[image: BST Example]

The max nodes in this Binary Search Tree would be 2 (Goes from 5 ->3->1 and excluding the root).

**What is the best way to approach this?**

---

I have seen this thread which is fairly similar to what I am trying to achieve.

[Count number of left nodes in BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075947/count-number-of-left-nodes-in-bst)

but there is like one line in the code that I don't understand.

```
count += countLeftNodes(overallRoot.left, count++);
```

> overallRoot.left

My guess is that it calls a function on the object, but I can't figure out what goes into that function and what it would return.

Any answers to these two questions would be appreciated.

Comment: @ggorlen Given that the OP stated 5,3,1 as the best case, it's pretty obvious that it's not overall count of left nodes, but longest chain of linked left nodes.  In which case for his stated question, 2 is the correct answer.

Comment: @dgnuff Yes, maybe I could have phrased it better, but this is what I meant.

Comment: Hummm.  I just noticed something.  The line of source you have quoted is actually undefined behavior.  Doing both `count += ...` and `count++` in the same statement is not permitted by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you linked shows how to traverse the tree, but you need a different algorithm to get your count, since as you have noted, that question is trying to solve a slightly different problem.

At any given point in the traversal, you will have the current left count: this will be passed down the tree as a second parameter to `countLeftNodes()`.  That starts with zero at the root, and is increased by one whenever you go into the left child of a node, but is set to zero when you enter the right node.

Then for both the left and right traversals, you set the left count to the greater of its current value, and the return from the recursive call to `countLeftNodes()`.  And then this final value is what you return from `countLeftNodes()`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shot at the algorithm @dgnuff illustrated:

```
void maxLeftNodesInPath(Node *root, int count, int *best) {
    if (root) {
        maxLeftNodesInPath(root->left, ++count, best);
        maxLeftNodesInPath(root->right, 0, best);
    }
    else if (count > *best) {
        *best = count - 1;
    }
}
```

The explanation is pretty much the same: keep accumulating on a count while traversing left, reset when moving to a right child, and if at a leaf, update the best.