# Accessing the left node with an iterator object in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

This is a function to find the maximum amount of left nodes. I do realize that there is already a thread for that:

[Count number of left nodes in BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075947/count-number-of-left-nodes-in-bst)

but I don't want pointers in my main file. So I am trying to find a slightly different approach.

```
bst<int>::binTreeIterator it;


int findMax(bst<int>::binTreeIterator it)
{
    int l = 0, r;
    if (!(it.leftSide() == NULL)) {
        l += 1 + findMax(it.leftSide());
    }

    if (!(it.rightSide() == NULL)) {
        r = findMax(it.rightSide());
    }

    return l;
}
```

my problem is with the leftSide()/rightSide() function; How do I implement them so that it returns an iterator object that points to the left side/ right side of the iterator "it" object?

```
template <class Type>
typename bst<Type>::binTreeIterator bst<Type>::binTreeIterator::leftSide()
{


}
```

Edit:

```
template <class Type>
class bst
{
    struct binTreeNode
    {
        binTreeNode * left;
        binTreeNode * right;
        Type item;
    };

public:
    class binTreeIterator
    {
    public:
        friend class bst;
        binTreeIterator();
        binTreeIterator(binTreeNode*);
        bool operator==(binTreeNode*);
        bool operator==(binTreeIterator);
        binTreeIterator rightSide();
        binTreeIterator leftSide();
    private:
        binTreeNode * current;
    };

    bst();
    bst(const bst<Type>&);
    const bst& operator=(const bst<Type>&);
    ~bst();
    void insert(const Type&);
    void display(); // TEST
    binTreeIterator begin();
    binTreeIterator end();

private:
    binTreeNode * insert(binTreeNode*, const Type&);
    void inorder(binTreeNode*);
    void destroyTree(binTreeNode*);
    void cloneTree(binTreeNode*, binTreeNode*);
    binTreeNode * root;
};
```

Comment: `!(it.leftSide() == NULL)` 1. prefer modern C++ keywords (`nullptr`) over old obsolete macros (`NULL`) 2. there is `!=` as well - so in total: `if(x != nullptr)` 3. (optional!) `if(pointer)` or, if checking for nullptr, `if(!pointer)`

Comment: There is no `std::bst`, so you should post your code for. Is there any reason for your left/right side functions not returning an iterator themselves?

Comment: If you're checking for equality with `nullptr` you are still dealing with pointers, just not explicitly. If you truly want to get rid of them, `std::reference_wrapper<>` provides an object that behaves like a reference, in that it must always point somewhere valid, but it can be "reseated". And if you want the semantic meaning of `nullptr` but without the risks of a `nullptr` dereference, wrapping the `reference_wrapper` up in a `std::optional<>` will get you there. Rather than exhibiting undefined behavior, if your `optional` is not set, you get well defined behavior: it throws an exception.

Comment: @Aconcagua No, they are supposed to return an iterator object that points to the left/right side of the iterator object "it". I will edit my code so it comes more clear

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand the point of even having `l` and `r` in that function. If you're counting the number of populated left nodes in the *entire* tree, you should be accumulating `1+count(left)` if `left` is non-empty, and *adding* `count(right)` if right is non-empty. That's it. Every non-empty left edge will accumulate all those +1's. Right now any left edges that require at least one right edge to reach will be discounted and ignored. Either that or I misunderstood the actual problem (wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: @WhozCraig; You are probably right, but my main problem is more that I don't know how to implement the leftSide (or rightSide) function to return an iterator object that points to the left ( or right) if the iterator object "it". I know that they behave like "r->left" "r->right".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very simple snipped of code should do the trick already:

```
template <class Type>
typename bst<Type>::binTreeIterator bst<Type>::binTreeIterator::leftSide()
{
    return current->left;
}
```

As you did not declare the iterator's constructor explicit, it will get called automatically from the pointer to left/right returned.

Comment: Thank you for your help. (I tried current = left... I need to work on my c++ fundamentals)